# How to execute Hive queries on Hive 2.1.1 on Spark 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Simple queries, e.g. `select`, work fine, but when I use aggregate functions, e.g. `count`, I face errors.

I use `beeline` to connect to Hive 2.1.1 with Spark 2.2.0 and Hadoop 2.8.

`hive-site.xml` is as follows:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
    <value>spark</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [mr, tez, spark].
      Chooses execution engine. Options are: mr (Map reduce, default), tez, spark. While MR
      remains the default engine for historical reasons, it is itself a historical engine
      and is deprecated in Hive 2 line. It may be removed without further warning.
    </description>
  </property>
<property>
<name>spark.master</name>
<value>spark://master:7077</value>
<description>Spark Master URL</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>Spark Event Log</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>
<value>hdfs://master:8020/user/spark/eventLogging</value>
<description>Spark event log folder</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.executor.memory</name>
<value>512m</value>
<description>Spark executor memory</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.serializer</name>
<value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
<description>Spark serializer</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.yarn.jars</name>
<value>hdfs://master:9000:/user/spark/spark-jars/*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.master</name>
<value>spark://master:7077</value>
<description>Spark Master URL</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>Spark Event Log</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>
<value>hdfs://master:8020/user/spark/eventLogging</value>
<description>Spark event log folder</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.executor.memory</name>
<value>512m</value>
<description>Spark executor memory</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.serializer</name>
<value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
<description>Spark serializer</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>spark.yarn.jars</name>
<value>hdfs://master:9000:/user/spark/spark-jars/*</value>
</property>
```

When executing `select count(*) from table` in hive I get the below error:

```
WARN thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error executing statement:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:225) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:276) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:324) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:499) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:486) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:295) ~[hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:506) [hive-service-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveConnection.java:1412) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.ExecuteStatement(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:308) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250) [hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
```

Comment: Can you execute any simpler query? What tool do you use to execute queries? beeline? Is this some kind of Hadoop distribution like Cloudera's CDH or HDP or MapR's?

Comment: Simple queriers like select are working. But when we use aggregate functions in query , we are facing error. Yes we use beeline to connect and using Apache Hadoop

Comment: How did you configure Hive on Spark? Any tutorials, blog posts or other documents? The error says that it can't find Scala classes that tells me that Hive on Spark is misconfigured and not ready to execute queries using Spark as the query engine.

Comment: Followed https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started  But here says Prior to Hive 2.2.0, link the spark-assembly jar to HIVE_HOME/lib.  There is no spark-assembly jar in hive 2.1.1  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373745/hive-on-spark-missing-spark-assembly-jar   Help me which versions are compatible both apache hive and  apache spark

Comment: select count(*) from student;
Query ID = hadoop_20180208184224_f86b5aeb-f27b-4156-bd77-0aab54c0ec67
Total jobs = 1
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask (state=08S01,code=1)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the other comment and the exception. I think what they refer to as `spark-assembly.jar` is the assembly from Spark and is not shipped with Hive.

Comment: Have you sorted it out?