# Spark Driver memory and Application Master memory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Am I understanding the documentation for client mode correctly?

1. client mode is opposed to cluster mode where the driver runs within the application master?
2. In client mode the driver and application master are separate processes and therefore `spark.driver.memory` + `spark.yarn.am.memory` must be less than the machine's memory?
3. In client mode is the driver memory is not included in the application master  memory setting?

Comment: Hi, if any of the answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or add your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 23):

> **client mode is opposed to cluster mode where the driver runs within the application master?**

**Yes**, When Spark application deployed over YARN in

- **Client mode**, driver will be running **in the machine where application got submitted** and the machine has to be available in the network till the application completes.
- **Cluster mode**, driver will be running in application master(one per spark application) node and machine submitting the application need not to be in network after submission

#### Client mode

[image: Client mode]

#### Cluster mode

[image: Cluster mode]

If Spark application is submitted with *cluster mode* on its own resource manager(standalone) then the driver process will be in one of the worker nodes.

References for images and content:

- [StackOverflow - Spark on yarn concept understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598830/1592191)
- [Cloudera Blog - Apache Spark Resource Management and YARN App Models](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/)

> **In client mode the driver and application master are separate processes and therefore `spark.driver.memory` + `spark.yarn.am.memory` must be less than the machine's memory?**

**No**, In **client mode**, driver and AM are **separate processes** and exists in **different machines**, so memory need not to be combined but `spark.yarn.am.memory` + `some overhead` should be less then YARN container memory(`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`). If it exceeds YARN's Resource Manager will kill the container.

> **In client mode is the driver memory is not included in the application master memory setting?**

Here `spark.driver.memory` must be less then the available memory in the machine from where the spark application is going to launch.

> But, **In cluster mode use `spark.driver.memory` instead of `spark.yarn.am.memory`**.
>
> > ### `spark.yarn.am.memory` :  512m (default)
> >
> > Amount of memory to use for the YARN Application Master in client mode, in the same format as JVM memory
> >     strings (e.g. `512m, 2g`). In cluster mode, use `spark.driver.memory`
> >     instead. Use lower-case suffixes, e.g. `k, m, g, t`, and `p`, for kibi-,
> >     mebi-, gibi-, tebi-, and pebibytes, respectively.
>
> Check [more about these properties here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties)

Comment: Great response. To clarify, the application master requests resources from the Resource Manager. But does the application master itself create the Yarn Containers and the Spark executors?

Comment: Thank you. This will be handled at YARN, Application master inform/request RM based on data size, and configurations to get the Yarn Containers to run Spark executors inside.

Answer (score 4):

In client mode, the driver is launched directly within the spark-submit i.e client program.  The application master to be created in any one of node in cluster. The spark.driver.memory (+ memory overhead) to be less than machine's memory.

In cluster mode, driver is running inside the application master in any of node in the cluster.

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/

Comment: where in that link does it say AM and driver is within the same process?

Comment: updated my response. AM can run in any of one of the node in the cluster and not in client machine.