# Spark application is using only one execeutor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am developing a spark application which is using the following spark context:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("example of SparkConnection")
  .config("spark.executor.instances", 10000)
  .getOrCreate();
```

I am trying to read data from csv and write it into the db tables. For this, I have a file of size 100KB. I want more than 1 executors to be used to read and write the file.

I have tried increasing the partitions using repartition method but still I am getting only one executor. Can some one help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allocate more executors per worker in Standalone cluster mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955133/how-to-allocate-more-executors-per-worker-in-standalone-cluster-mode)

Comment: I see that you are using `local` master. With `local` master the spark application is executed in single JVM on local machine itself. There is not much significance of executor instances with `local` master.