# One worker with two executor vs One worker per executor in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using `spark-1.6` with standalone resource manager in `client mode`. Now, as it is supported to run multiple `executors` per `worker` in spark. Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of running which one should be preferred for the production environment?

Moreover, when spark comes with the pre-built binaries of hadoop-2.x why do we need to setup another `hadoop` cluster to run it in the `yarn` mode. What's the point of packing those jars in the spark. And what's the point of using the `yarn` when flexibility of multiple executors per worker is given in standalone mode

Comment: I think you can find some similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621990/what-are-workers-executors-cores-in-spark-standalone-cluster

Comment: @HarishPathak I have already saw that post before posting the question here. it doesn't answer my question