# Spark num-executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have setup a 10 node HDP platform on AWS. Below is my configuration
2 Servers - Name Node and Standby Name node
7 Data Nodes and each node has 40 vCPU and 160 GB of memory.

I am trying to calculate the number of executors while submitting spark applications and after going through different blogs I am confused on what this parameter actually means.

Looking at the below blog it seems the num executors are the total number of executors across all nodes
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

But looking at the below blog it seems that the num executors is per node or server
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx578UTQUV7LRP/Submitting-User-Applications-with-spark-submit

Can anyone please clarify and review the below :-

1. Is the num-executors value is per node or the total number of executors across all the data nodes.
2. I am using the below calculation to come up with the core count, executor count and memory per executor

   Number of cores <= 5 (assuming 5)
   Num executors = (40-1)/5 = 7 
   Memory = (160-1)/7 = 22 GB

With the above calculation which would be the correct way

```
--master yarn-client --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 22G --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 5 

OR

--master yarn-client --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 22G --num-executors 49 --executor-cores 5
```

Thanks,
Jayadeep

Comment: As [nicely spotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399205/spark-standalone-number-executors-cores-control/39400195#comment66127571_39400195) by [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3729739/marco) `num-executors` has been removed in 2.0+.

Comment: Thanks, i am currently using Spark 1.6.0 and would like to know how these parameters are used and calculated

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please clarify and review the below :-
>
> 1. Is the num-executors value is per node or the total number of executors across all the data nodes.

You need to first understand that the executors run on the NodeManagers (You can think of this like workers in Spark standalone). A number of **Containers** (includes vCPU, memory, network, disk, etc.) equal to **number of executors** specified will be allocated for your Spark application on YARN. Now these executor containers will be run on multiple NodeManagers and that depends on the [CapacityScheduler](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_yarn_resource_mgt/content/flexible_scheduling_policies.html) (default scheduler in HDP).

So to sum up, total number of executors is the number of **resource containers** you specify for your application to run.

Refer [this](https://www.mapr.com/blog/resource-allocation-configuration-spark-yarn) blog to understand better.

> 2. I am using the below calculation to come up with the core count, executor count and memory per executor
>
> Number of cores <= 5 (assuming 5) Num executors = (40-1)/5 = 7 Memory = (160-1)/7 = 22 GB

There is no rigid formula for calculating the number of executors. Instead you can try enabling [Dynamic Allocation in YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation) for your application.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, so if I understand correctly, the executors are defined at an application level and is not setup per node. Based on the capacity scheduler the executors will be provisioned across the data nodes. 

Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

There is a hiccup with the capacity scheduler. As far as I understand it allows you to only schedule by memory. You will first need to change that to the dominant resource calculator scheduling type. That will allow you to ask for more memory and cores combination. Once you change that out you should be able to ask for both cup and memory with your spark application.

As for --num-executors flag, you can even keep it at a very high value of 1000. It will still allocate only the number of containers that is possible to launch on each node. As and when your cluster resources increase your containers attached to your application will increase. The number of containers that you can launch per node will be limited by the amount of resources allocated to the nodemanagers on those nodes.