# Spark standalone configuration having multiple executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to setup a standalone Spark 2.0 server to process an analytics function in parallel.  To do this I want to have a single worker with multiple executors.

I'm using :

- Standalone Spark 2.0
- 8 Cores
- 24gig RAM
- windows server 2008
- pyspark (although this appears unrelated)

This is just for pure proof of concept purposes but I want to have 8 executors, one per each core.

I've tried to follow the other threads on this topic but for some reason it's not working for me.  IE:
[Spark Standalone Number Executors/Cores Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399205/spark-standalone-number-executors-cores-control)

My configuration is as follows:

**conf\spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.cores.max = 8
spark.executor.cores = 1
```

I have tried to also change my spark-env.sh file to no avail.  Instead what is happening is that it shows that my 1 worker only has 1 executor on it.  As you can see below, it still shows the standalone with 1 executor with 8 cores to it.

[image]

Comment: If you want to simulate running a cluster locally you can use docker compose https://dev.to/mvillarrealb/creating-a-spark-standalone-cluster-with-docker-and-docker-compose-2021-update-6l4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you mixed up local and standalone modes:

- **Local mode** is a development tool where all processes are executed inside a single JVM. Application is started in a local mode by setting master to `local`, `local[*]` or `local[n]`. `spark.executor.cores` and `spark.executor.cores` are not applicable in the local mode because there is only one embedded executor.
- **Standalone mode** requires a standalone [Spark cluster](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html). It requires a master node (can be started using `SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh` script) and at least one worker node (can be started using `SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh` script).

  `SparkConf` should use master node address to create (`spark://host:port`).

Answer (score 4):

You first need to configure your spark standalone cluster, then set the amount of resources needed for each individual spark application you want to run.

In order to configure the cluster, you can try this:

In conf/spark-env.sh:

`Set the SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES = 10`

which determines the number of Worker instances (#Executors) per node (its default value is only 1)

`Set the SPARK_WORKER_CORES = 15`

number of cores that one Worker can use (default: all cores, your case is 36)

`Set SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 55g`

total amount of memory that can be used on one machine (Worker Node) for running Spark programs.
Copy this configuration file to all Worker Nodes, on the same folder
Start your cluster by running the scripts in sbin (sbin/start-all.sh, ...)
As you have 5 workers, with the above configuration you should see 5 (workers) * 10 (executors per worker) = 50 alive executors on the master's web interface (http://localhost:8080 by default)

When you run an application in standalone mode, by default, it will acquire all available Executors in the cluster. You need to explicitly set the amount of resources for running this application: Eg:

`val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster(...)
             .setAppName(...)
             .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
             .set("spark.cores.max", "10")`

Comment: What do you mean by "copy this configuration file to all Worker Nodes"? Is there a file that I have to make and paste these configurations in?