# Increase Spark executors barely increase the performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I m trying to measure the performance in Spark depending on the number of executors and cores .
The idea is to play with:

```
   spark.conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "x")
   spark.conf.set('spark.cores.max', 'x')
```

to test the  impvoe of performance of Spark when I change the number of executors and cores.
Data is 1.66GB Twitter files .json
I m working wiht a computer hp:

Prozessor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90Ghz 2.11GHz
             // 16 GB RAM

```
 import time
 st = time.time()
 print("start time: ", st)

 #### Code  ####

elapsed_time = time.time() - st
print("...Elapsed time SPARK: %.2fs" % elapsed_time)
```

I discover that the performance barely change if I use in executors 1,3,5

for example

```
   import time
   st = time.time()
   print("start time: ", st)
   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
   spark.conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "1")
   spark.conf.set('spark.cores.max', '1')
   df = spark.read.json(mount + '/*/*.json.bz2' )
   elapsed_time = time.time() - st
   print("...Elapsed time SPARK: %.2fs" % elapsed_time)
```

1: 1 executor, 1 core start time:  1549530285.584573
...Elapsed time SPARK: 315.52s

2: 3 executor,3 core start time:  1549528358.4399529
...Elapsed time SPARK: 308.30s

3: 5 executor,5 core start time:  1549528690.1516254
...Elapsed time SPARK: 289.28s

Are that improve normal? I was expecting something much more significant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: Inconsistent performance number in scaling number of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090127/spark-inconsistent-performance-number-in-scaling-number-of-cores)

Comment: Additionally, is that `local` mode or standalone? If the former one, [these settings have no use at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39986507/10465355).

Answer (score 2):

Spark performance depends on different factors like workload type, partitioning scheme, data skew, memory consumption etc. You can check the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html) for more information.

Secondly you cannot change executor count on the fly. It is stated in [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) as;

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
>   to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”,
>   this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
>   programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is
>   depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
>   would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit
>   command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime
>   control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be
>   set in either way.

Comment: Hi Sgungormus, what do you mean with "you cannot change executor count on the fly" I m making differents proyects with hist own Sparksession.

Comment: @Enrique I don't know your exact confuguration but once SparkSession is initialized executor counts cannot be changed via setting conf parameters. Those parameters should be set in the spark-submit or spark-shell command.