# Spark Job using more executors than allocated in jobs

Tags: apache-spark

I have following settings in my Spark job:

```
--num-executors 2 
--executor-cores 1 
--executor-memory 12G 
--driver memory 16G 
--conf spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=false 
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=8192 
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=8192'
```

My understanding is job should run with 2 executors however it is running with 3. This is happening to multiple of my jobs. Could someone please explain the reason?

Comment: [Spark Standalone Number Executors/Cores Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39399205/10465355)

Comment: We made sure to have dynamic allocation as false, so that job uses fix amount of resources.