# spark standalone cluster: how to limit number of workers?

Tags: apache-spark

Example:

spark standalone cluster add 1 machine(16 cpus) as worker

1. commit application not setting `spark.executor.cores` then it will create

   1 worker with 16 cores
2. commit with `spark.executor.cores=15` then it will create 1 worker with 15 cores
3. commit with `spark.executor.cores=5` then it will create 3 workers with 5 cores each worker

Now i want to limit cpu usage, only want 5 cores to be used

my question is:

how to set only 1 worker with 5 cores

Comment: spark.cores.max=5

Answer (score 0):

Check this question please. I think it's a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400195/7779865

I think you can try to set spark.executor.cores=5 and spark.cores.max=5 or use spark.deploy.defaultCores=5 instead of spark.cores.max

[Read about spark.max.cores here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/configuration.html#scheduling)

[Read about spark.deplo.defaultCores here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)