# What is the difference between SPARK Partitions and Worker Cores?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I used the `Standalone Spark Cluster` to process several files. When I executed the Driver, the data was processed on each worker using it's cores.

Now, I've read about `Partitions`, but I didn't get it if it's different than Worker Cores or not.

Is there a difference between setting `cores number` and `partition numbers`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are workers, executors, cores in Spark Standalone cluster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621990/what-are-workers-executors-cores-in-spark-standalone-cluster)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplistic view: Partition vs Number of Cores

When you invoke an action an RDD,

- A "Job" is created for it. So, Job is a work submitted to spark.
- Jobs are divided in to "STAGE" based on the shuffle boundary!!!
- Each stage is further divided to tasks based on the number of partitions on the RDD. So Task is smallest unit of work for spark.
- Now, how many of these tasks can be executed simultaneously depends on the "Number of Cores" available!!!

Answer (score 4):

Partition (or task) refers to a unit of work.  If you have a 200G hadoop file loaded as an RDD and chunked by 128M (Spark default), then you have ~2000 partitions in this RDD.  The number of cores determines how many partitions can be processed at any one time, and up to 2000 (capped at the number of partitions/tasks) can execute this RDD in parallel.

Comment: So If I have a 70 cores and my input parquet has 1000 partitions, it means I can only process 70 tasks at a time correct? In which case, I am wasting the remaining 930 tasks time. However if i repartition my dataset to just 70 or 100, I might get a very large file size per partition.