# Why is the data not getting added to the map while the same function can by used to print dataset to console. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, hashmap

```java
dataset = dataset.withColumn("Probability", callUDF("checkProb", col("Confirmed"), col("Population")));
    
Map<String, Double> probability= new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> a =new ArrayList<>();
dataset= dataset.limit(35);
dataset.show(36);
dataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> a.add(row.getAs("State").toString()));
                    
System.out.println(a.size());
```

the size prints 0 no matter what i do. i have tried arraylist and map but doesn't work.

Comment: Does your dataset contain any element before you call the foreach?

Comment: You should let us see what this dataset is all about. As @aBnormaLz said, it might not contains any element at all.

Comment: This code does not use the map, only a list. So your title and tags are erroneous and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark distributes the workload to different [executors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32628057/2129801). The driver process provides a *copy* of each local variable for each executor. This copy is independent of the original variable and if an executor alters the copy, the original variable stays unchanged. `foreach` is run by the executors, and each executor gets its own copy of `a`. You can see that if you print the [identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) of the `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
dataset = dataset.limit(35);
dataset.show(36);
System.out.println("a in the driver process: " + System.identityHashCode(a));
dataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
    a.add(row.getAs("value").toString());
    System.out.println("a on an executor " + System.identityHashCode(a));
});
System.out.println("back in the driver process: " + System.identityHashCode(a));
```

prints

```
a in the driver process: 1859780907
a on an executor 229101481
a on an executor 2105534525
a on an executor 1982276971
back in the driver process: 1859780907
```

Therefore, the `ArrayList` on which you call `size()` gets never altered.

Btw: it is a bad practice to use the driver's local variables on the executors as this may cause (not only performance) problems. You should consider using [broadcast variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) and [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators).