# In the following scala code the desired string is not printed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Why does the accumulator variable in the following code does not print the aggregated string?

```
object mapRDD {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("sparkSessionName")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val data = Seq("Project",
      "Gutenberg’s",
      "Alice’s",
      "Adventures",
      "in",
      "Wonderland")

    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

    var accumulator: String = "WHY IS THE AGGREGATED STRING NOT PRINTED?"
    for (eachElementOfRDD <- rdd) {
      accumulator = accumulator ++ eachElementOfRDD
    }
    println(accumulator)
  }
}
```

**Output**
*21/05/13 09:10:52 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager host.docker.internal:64786 with 894.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, host.docker.internal, 64786, None)
21/05/13 09:10:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, host.docker.internal, 64786, None)
21/05/13 09:10:52 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, host.docker.internal, 64786, None)
WHY IS THE AGGREGATED STRING NOT PRINTED?*

I am a newbie to spark and scala and I understand the output of the following code is correct. What I want to know is the reason for such a behaviour. What this concept is called and some pointers to understand it.

**EDIT**
The variable name accumulator was a co-incidence to the accumulator functionality of spark. I am concerned with adding a string to the original string until the loop is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Two things should be changed in the code to get the expected output:

- create an accumulator using [SparkContext.collectionAccumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#collectionAccumulator%5BT%5D(name:String):org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator%5BT%5D)
- iterate over the elements of the rdd using [RDD.foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit)

```scala
val accumulator = spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[String]
rdd.foreach( eachElementOfRDD => accumulator.add(eachElementOfRDD))
println(accumulator.value)
```

Output:

```
[Project, Gutenberg’s, Alice’s, Adventures, in, Wonderland]
```

Comment: My concern is that the code using 
for (eachElementOfRDD <- rdd) {
      accumulator = accumulator ++ eachElementOfRDD
    }
the eachElementOfRDD gets added to accumulator variable
But outside the loop its value is unchanged.

Comment: @mannat please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287430/2129801). Does this help?