# How does Spark perform I/O?

Tags: apache-spark, io, parallel-io

It is my understanding that Spark uses parallel IO to read files. That conclusion comes from other stack overflow responses.

My question is does spark read data using an independent approach or a collective approach? In other words, does each worker read a set chunk of data, or do the workers communicate with each other and collaborate to efficiently read data?

Answer (score 1):

Each **Apache Spark workers**  has Executors, Workers can be deployed as distributed or standalone mode.
Each Worker process its own data that it processes.
For more detail see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696777/what-is-the-relationship-between-workers-worker-instances-and-executors) or this [link](https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/using-spark-as-a-parallel-processing-framework-for-accessing-rest-based-data-services-cd4c98526784)

Comment: To install Spark Standalone mode, you simply place a compiled version of Spark on each node on the cluster. I am wondering if you are not confusing things?

Comment: @thebluephantom it doesn't talk about installation

Answer (score 1):

The workers communicate by the driver And each  worker process its own data