# How multiple executors are managed on the worker nodes with a Spark standalone cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, cluster-computing, apache-spark-standalone

Until now, I have only used Spark on a Hadoop cluster with YARN as the resource manager. In that type of cluster, I know exactly how many executors to run and how the resource management works. However, know that I am trying to use a Standalone Spark Cluster, I have got a little bit confused. Correct me where I am wrong.

From [this article](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), by default, a worker node uses all the memory of the node minus 1 GB. But I understand that by using `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`, we can use lesser memory. For example, if the total memory of the node is 32 GB, but I specify 16 GB, Spark worker is not going to use anymore than 16 GB on that node?

But what about executors? Let us say if I want to run 2 executors per node, can I do that by specifying executor memory during `spark-submit` to be half of `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`, and if I want to run 4 executors per node, by specifying executor memory to be the quarter of `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`?

If so, besides executor memory, I would also have to specify executor cores correctly, I think. For example, if I want to run 4 executors on a worker, I would have to specify executor cores to be the quarter of `SPARK_WORKER_CORES`? What happens, if I specify a bigger number than that? I mean if I specify executor memory to be the quarter of `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`, but executor cores to be only half of `SPARK_WORKER_CORES`? Would I get 2 or 4 executors running on that node in that case?

Comment: Can you check if the acceptable answer still makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I experimented with the Spark Standalone cluster myself a bit, and this is what I noticed.

1. My intuition that muliple executors can be run inside a worker, by tuning executor cores was indeed correct. Let us say, your worker has 16 cores. Now if you specify 8 cores for executors, Spark would run 2 executors per worker.
2. How many executors run inside a worker also depend upon the executor memory you specify. For example, if worker memory is 24 GB, and you want to run 2 executors per worker, you cannot specify executor memory to be more than 12 GB.
3. A worker's memory can be limited when starting a slave by specifing the value for optional parameter`--memory` or by changing the value of `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`. Same with the number of cores (`--cores`/`SPARK_WORKER_CORES`).

If you want to be able to run multiple jobs on the Standalone Spark cluster, you could use the `spark.cores.max` configuration property while doing `spark-submit`. For example, like this.

```
spark-submit <other parameters> --conf="spark.cores.max=16" <other parameters>
```

So, if your Standalone Spark Cluster allows 64 cores in total, and you give only 16 cores to your program, other Spark jobs could use the remaining 48 cores.

Comment: Look at my comment in the above, it doesn't work as expected and I can confirm the same from another stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thanks @skjagini for pointing it out. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way to control number of executors, cores and memory in my experience.

- Cores: You can set total number of cores across all executors and number of cores per each executor
- Memory: Executor memory individually

  --total-executor-cores 12 --executor-cores 2  --executor-memory 6G

  This would give you 6 executors and 2 cores/6G per each executor, so in total you are looking at 12 Cores and 36G
- You can set driver memory using

  --driver-memory 2G

Comment: Who said you cannot specify the number of executors? Because I do it all the times using --num-executors with spark-submit.

Comment: I have tried --num-executors 6 and executors cores 3. We have a cluster with 6 nodes and 12 cores each, I ended up with 23 executors with 3 cores when I launched a job, doesn't look like it makes sense.

Comment: @MetallicPriest I can confirm the same from another post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399205/spark-standalone-number-executors-cores-control Check your facts