# Spark: How to utilize all cores and memory on spark stand alone cluster, where nodes differs in memory size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

How to utilize all cores and memory on the spark standalone cluster below:

```
Node 1: 4cores 8gb memory
Node 2: 4cores 16gb memory
```

Currently I can allocate to use:

A)  8 cores and 14 gb of memory by setting:

```
.config('spark.executor.memory','7g')
.config('spark.executor.cores', '4')

Cores       |  Memory
----------------------------------
4 (4 Used)  |  15.0 GiB (7.0 GiB Used)  
4 (4 Used)  |  7.0 GiB (7.0 GiB Used)
```

B) To use 6 cores and 21gb of memory by setting:

```
.config('spark.executor.memory','7g')
.config('spark.executor.cores', '2')

Cores       |  Memory
----------------------------------
4 (4 Used)  |  15.0 GiB (14.0 GiB Used) 
4 (2 Used)  |  7.0 GiB (7.0 GiB Used)
```

Expected output:

```
 8 cores 21gb of memory:

    Cores       |  Memory
    ----------------------------------
    4 (4 Used)  |  15.0 GiB (14.0 GiB Used) 
    4 (4 Used)  |  7.0 GiB (7.0 GiB Used)
```

ref:

1. [What are workers, executors, cores in Spark Standalone cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621990/what-are-workers-executors-cores-in-spark-standalone-cluster/32628057#32628057)
2. [Spark Standalone Number Executors/Cores Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399205/spark-standalone-number-executors-cores-control)
3. [How multiple executors are managed on the worker nodes with a Spark standalone cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364403/how-multiple-executors-are-managed-on-the-worker-nodes-with-a-spark-standalone-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the answer is very simple. I tried YARN and I had the same problem as with Standalone. I found that solution for Standalone setting is in the end very simple by settings in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh on the each Node:

For Node 1: (4cores 8gb memory)

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=7g
```

Node 2: (4cores 16gb memory)

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=14g
```

And running spark app with setting

```
.config('spark.executor.memory','7g')
.config('spark.executor.cores', '2')
```

All 8 cores 21gb of memory is used as a result:

```
 Cores       |  Memory
    ----------------------------------
    8 (8 Used)  |  14.0 GiB (14.0 GiB Used) 
    4 (4 Used)  |  7.0 GiB (7.0 GiB Used)
```

Note: In YARN the problem can be solved the same way. Setting in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml is required to change for parameters below:

```
   <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
                <value>7168</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
                <value>7168</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
                <value>512</value>
        </property>

         <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
                <value>4</value>
        </property>

        <property>
              <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
              <value>1</value>
        </property>

        <property>
              <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
              <value>2</value>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have a cluster which has a size of two nodes: so you have to use a resource manager like [YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) (IMHO). Otherwise your spark-job will only be executed on your local machine.
- Use this: [Running Spark on YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)
- Example B) showes that 4 cores are allocated but currently only two are used to do the work. The other two cores are just bored and have nothing to do or finished their work